# Inside Component 'dispatch' is not defined no-undef error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk

Inside my component

```
  setDealSizeAndType({ target }){
    this.setState(
      {
      type: target.name
      }, function(){
      dispatch(setTypeAndDealSize(this.state.patientDealSize , this.state.type)
    )
    });
    console.log(this.state.patientDealSize , "abc" , this.state.type);
  }
```

I am getting an error that error:

> 'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef.

I am not able to dispatch this action because of this.

Comment: You have to pass dispatch to it somehow, may be connet your actions or
if it is asynchronous return a function after using redux-thunk

Comment: having actions dispatch other actions requires middleware. Redux-thunk is a popular choice, as stated above